# How to merge two subarrays in JavaScript without changing the order of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to merge two subarrays inside an array without pushing them to the end of the array

```
let array = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"]];
array[1] = array[1].concat[2];
```

So I basically want `array` to be

```
array = [["a"], ["bc"], ["d"]];
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can do that using [Array.reduce(..)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could splice the array and remove the item for adding to another item.

```js
let array = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"]];

array[1][0] += array.splice(2, 1).join('');

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']];

arr[1][0] += arr[2][0];
arr.splice(2, 1);
console.log(arr);
```